# Can I add a space for people to write notes: like dietary needs and or comments?

Tags: webform-civicrm

Can I add a space for people to write notes: like dietary needs and or comments??

Is there a way to add a memo field?

Comment: Hi Deb! Welcome to the stackexchange for CiviCRM - can you share what CMS you are using, and what version of CiviCRM you are using.

Can you also share if this is only for you, as a CiviCRM administrator to write notes, or you want this for something someone in the public could write notes. There are about 50 ways to answer your question so some further clarification would be super helpful.

Comment: Agree more info needed, and every contact already has a tab on their contact page called "Notes" where you can add notes, so need to know if you mean something different?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with custom field set for individuals with two fields, one a multiple choice (All, Vegetarian, Vegan, Special) and the second a text field to show anything else. I also included disability (yes/no field and a text field for detailed requirements in the same field set as both sets of info are needed in relation to courses booked. There are lots of ways to do it and the user documentation tells you all about custom fields.

Having the structured and unstructured fields allows you to search, but also include additional information.