# How to add Contact "Notes" field in webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm, forms

I need to create a signup form via webform and would like to include a Notes section where people can make write something  during signup. I would like that to appear in the "Notes" section of contact. Cant seem to locate that option, any ideas please? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's a similar question: [Can I add a space for people to write notes: like dietary needs and or comments?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29072/can-i-add-a-space-for-people-to-write-notes-like-dietary-needs-and-or-comments)

And here's an outstanding request for the feature here: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/2320295

The conclusion is: consider putting the note somewhere else, e.g. an activity or custom field.

Although the notes field seems like the right place, it's not a bad idea to NOT put it there, since the notes field tends to be private for administrators and hiding the contact's notes in there means they might not get seen.

If you work forwards and think about what those notes are for, that might suggest a better location. A custom field seems like the right answer.

Comment: In addition - consider if the Note is something you want to permanently store in CiviCRM. If there is no need for that just create a Drupal field on the form and store it on the Drupal submission only.